# Vector of buffers in C++

Tags: c++, vector, buffer, stdvector, unique-ptr

I've created this vector, which has buffers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<locked_buffer<std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>>>>> v1;
```

Then, I fill this vector with `n` buffers and this buffers have `aux` elements. `n` is an int number which is an argument. `aux`is another argument that is an int type too.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   v1.push_back(std::unique_ptr<locked_buffer<std::pair<int,std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>>>> (new locked_buffer<std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>>>(aux)));  
}
```

But when I try to access to each buffer of the vector I can't, because I haven't got clear how can I access to a specific element of a vector structure:

```
v1[0].put(image, false);
```

The compilation error that I've got is the following one (The `put` function is defined on my custom `locked_buffer` structure):

```
error: ‘_gnu_cxx::_alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<locked_buffer<std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > > > > > >::value_type {aka class std::unique_ptr<locked_buffer<std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > > > >}’ has no member named ‘put’
v1[i].put(image, false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to dereference the `unique_ptr`, so do `v1[i]->put...`

Comment: is that double vector at the end supposed to be a 2d matrix? also, this would be a great place to use `using`. Such as `template<class T> using myBufferType = std::pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<T>>>;` and then your type is `std::unique_ptr<locked_buffer<myBufferType<unsigned char>>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v1[0]` is a `unique_ptr<locked_buffer<...>>`. In order to call a method on the contained `locked_buffer`, you need to dereference the `unique_ptr`, i.e.

```
(*v1[0]).put(image, false);
```

or

```
v1[0]->put(image, false);
```